# jQuery TagIt: autocomplete is not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, tags

I am using jquery tagit api and i have written my code like

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#mytags").tagit({
    tagSource: function(search, showChoices) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/UI/user/taggin.php",
        data: {search: search.term},
        success: function(choices) {
          showChoices(choices);
        }
      });
    }
  });
  });
```

And here is my html

```
            <tr>                        
                    <td>Tags</td>
                        <td><input id="mytags"  class= "ulc" name = "mytags"></ul>
                    </td>

                </tr>
```

my `http://localhost/UI/user/taggin.php` is returning data like

```
["tag1","tag2","surgeon"]
```

In json format

Please tell me what i am doing wrong so my auto-complete  is not working here

Comment: jquery chosen is better than tagit

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
tagSource: function(search, showChoices) {
    var that = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: "/tags/autocomplete.json",
        data: {
            q: search.term
        },
        success: function(choices) {
            showChoices(that._subtractArray(choices, that.assignedTags()));
        }
    });
}​
```

Take a look on this [github issue](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/issues/13#issuecomment-1833137)

Answer (score 0):

[Jquery UI's autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) is another option.